# Regularizing effects present in the group $\{e^{it\Delta}\}$.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, dispersive-pde

[image]

I'm trying to understand the demonstration above.

For 1, if $g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\notin L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it is clear that
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{L^2} = \|e^{-it_{0}\Delta}g\|_{L^2} &= \|g\|_{L^2} < +\infty\\
\|e^{it_0\Delta}f\|_{L^p} = \|e^{it_0\Delta}e^{-it_{0}\Delta}g\|_{L^p} &= \|g\|_{L^p} = +\infty,
\end{align}
Moreover, I don't know if I should choose a specific function that satisfies those hypotheses.
For instance:

If $g(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon}}\chi_{[0,1]}$, then it belongs $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but not to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p>2$. I don't know how to generalise this to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For 2, I don't understand how he concludes that $e^{it\Delta}\notin H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: You talk about some free variable $\Delta$,vI would guess this should not be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1: I suppose you could just take
$$ g(x) = \vert x \vert^{\varepsilon - \frac{1}{2}} \mathbf{1}_{B_1(0)}.$$
Ad 2: The computation in the proof shows that if $e^{it\Delta}f\in H^{s_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then also $f = e^{-it\Delta}(e^{it\Delta})f\in H^{s_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now, if you suppose that $e^{it\Delta}f\in H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then ultimately $f\in H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $f\not\in H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!